# Sending text box values from my website to gmail to login into the gmail

Tags: php, javascript

I have two text boxes in my webpage as username and submit button.

1)Firstly user needs to give username,password,then presses the submit button.

2)After pressing submit button,I want to send those username and password values to gmail website for logging into gmail..

3) Means,user will be logging into gmail without visiting gmail login page...

Comment: I have to say, this sounds a bit on the creepy side to me.  I realize that you may not intend it this way, but I read what you're trying to do, and my gut reaction is that it's a site intended to acquire passwords inappropriately.

Comment: @Ben I agree, he needs to be using openid, which allows google account authentication, just like someone could log in to a site with their facebook or twitter account.

Comment: @jzworkman: maybe he wants to create gmail accounts?

Comment: @symcbean creating gmail accounts through a separate website is against their ToS(you would have to purchase a google apps license to do that)

Comment: sorry friends i dont want to allow google account authentication... i want to login into gmail page without visiting the gmail login page... i dont want use any openid's............

Comment: That is not possible. It would go against all sorts of security practices to allow people to do that.  There is a reason you can only login from the google login page(to prevent phishing attempts and invalid logins)

Answer (score 3):

Quick google search:

http://qpleple.com/how-to-make-people-login-into-your-website-with-their-google-account/

This is a tutorial for openId which you can use to allow your users to login with gmail, facebook, twitter, yahoo, etc

Comment: Thanks for replying.. i want to login into gmail without visiting the gmail login page.. User name and password will be taken as input from my website... is it possible?

Comment: You have to use a service like openId in order to do that.  And that will only allow people to log in to your site.  You will not be able to access a gmail account from your site(you have to visit gmail to do that)